# is there a way to make the coad read a txt file and tell me what the each of the names gender is

Tags: python

my code

```
import requests,json

name = ("hika")
content = requests.get(f"https://api.genderize.io/?name={name}").text
gender = json.loads(content)['gender']

print(f"Gender of {name} is {gender}")
```

I want to make it reads a txt file and tells me which names are males and which are females

Comment: Works for me. What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: i  want it to read a whole txt file and tell me there genders

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense. Sorry I didn't catch that from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code [reading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/) names from `path_to_txt_file.txt` file:

```py
import requests,json

with open("path_to_txt_file.txt", "r") as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    name = line.strip()
    content = requests.get(f"https://api.genderize.io/?name={name}").text
    gender = json.loads(content)['gender']

    print(f"Gender of {name} is {gender}")
    with open(f"{gender}.txt", "a") as fw:
      fw.write(name + "\n")
```

Comment: thanks. but can I save the females and males in a different txt file?

Comment: Updated answer.